# With Google's Family Link, how to grant unlimited access to select apps?

Tags: parental-control, google-family-link

I just have set up Google Family Link parental control. It very nice and seems to work well for the most part.

However, I want to allow some apps (e.g. Wikipedia) without screen time restriction. I have found ways to give app permissions selectively, but not usage restrictions selectively.

**How to exclude some select apps from the screen time limit?**

**Additionally, is there a way to exclude/allow select apps from the device lock?** (E.g. I would like to allow to play music even at bedtime, but nothing else)

Comment: Have you checked the following link? https://support.google.com/families/answer/7101025?hl=en

Comment: @KennethM Yes I have, among other explainers, mostly from google themselves. It's quite clearly written but does not say anything about individual app usage. The usage restrictions seem to apply regardless of what app was used, which I am asking specifically about here.

Answer (score 0):

Your first request is now possible.  Set the app(s) to "Always allow".  [(Source.)](https://support.google.com/families/answer/7103340)

Your second request is still impossible.  After bedtime, "Always allowed" apps can no longer be used.  [(Source.)](https://www.androidpolice.com/2021/03/16/new-family-link-options-make-parents-lives-easier-but-key-features-are-still-missing/)  If necessary, consider giving your child an old MP3 or CD player which can play music.  Or, you could simply allow your child to fall asleep without music.

---

Since you mentioned Wikipedia:

Wikipedia is not censored.  It includes some graphic material relating to sex, and other graphic material relating to violence.  This material includes text, photos, and videos.  Do you really want your child to be able to access this material in the middle of the night?

Please consider blocking Wikipedia on your kid's phone completely.  The kid can still use Wikipedia on a computer in your living room, or in the school library; these are probably safer places to use Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks for the update about "always allow". I consider Wikipedia one of the more curated pages out there, so no, I do not intend to block it at all.